# how to check ec2 instance-type availability in regions and availability zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can we tell which regions and availability zones an instance type is available in? I am looking for to check for c5.xlarge instance type.

i already have one query but that is not giving me proper output.

```
aws --profile qa ec2 describe-reserved-instances-offerings --filters Name=scope,Values=availability-zone --no-include-marketplace --instance-type 'c5.xlarge' | jq -r '.ReservedInstancesOfferings[].AvailabilityZone' | sort | uniq
```

is there also any other way?

Answer (score 2):

I got the list by running below commands region wise.

1. C:\Users\sachinsin>aws --profile qa ec2 describe-reserved-instances-offerings --filters "Name=scope,Values=Availability Zone" --no-include-marketplace --instance-type c5.xlarge --region ap-southeast-2 >> ap-southeast-2.txt
2. C:\Users\sachinsin>aws --profile qa ec2 describe-reserved-instances-offerings --filters "Name=scope,Values=Availability Zone" --no-include-marketplace --instance-type c5.xlarge --region us-west-2 >> us-west-2.txt
3. C:\Users\sachinsin>aws --profile qa ec2 describe-reserved-instances-offerings --filters "Name=scope,Values=Availability Zone" --no-include-marketplace --instance-type c5.xlarge --region eu-west-1 >> eu-west-1.txt

Comment: When I try this I get the error "The config profile (qa) could not be found". I got around this by omitting the "--profile qa" portion of the command